# Show that $X^T_{(-i)} X_{(-i)} = X^TX - x_ix^T_i$.

Tags: linear-algebra

$X$ is an $n$ x $p$ matrix with rank $p$, and $X_{(-i)}$ is an $(n-1)$ x $p$ matrix that is the same as $X$ but with the $i$th row removed. $x_i^T$ represents this row.

I've tested this in MATLAB and it makes sense: removing a row from the matrix and taking $X^T_{(-i)} X_{(-i)}$ is the same as using the full matrix and taking away $x_ix^T_i$. I've tried to prove this using a general case of $X$, but it seems more tedious to prove it this way and I feel like there is an easier method, possibly using the fact that $X$ is of full rank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(**Edit:** added the zero-blocks explicitly, thus making the computations look neater.)

Consider the $n$-order identity matrix
$$I_n =\begin{bmatrix} 
I_{i-1}& {\bf 0}_{i-1}& {\bf 0}_{(i-1)\times(n-i)}\\ 
{\bf 0}^{\rm T}_{i-1}& 1& {\bf 0}^{\rm T}_{n-i}\\
{\bf 0}_{(n-i)\times(i-1)}& {\bf 0}_{n-i}& I_{n-i}
\end{bmatrix},$$
where the $i$th row (let us call it $e^{(n)\rm T}_i$) and column are somewhat highlighted, and the bolded zeros are blocks of zeros (columns or blocks, according to the subscripts).
Removing a row from $I_n$ and then multiplying it from the left to another matrix  $M$ is the same as deleting the corresponding row in $M$, thus we can express $X_{(-i)}$ as
$$X_{(-i)} :=\begin{bmatrix} 
I_{i-1}& {\bf 0}_{i-1}& {\bf 0}_{(i-1)\times(n-i)}\\ 
{\bf 0}_{(n-i)\times(i-1)}& {\bf 0}_{n-i}& I_{n-i}
\end{bmatrix} X.$$
Taking the transpose:
$$X^{\rm T}_{(-i)} =X^{\rm T} \begin{bmatrix} 
I_{i-1}& {\bf 0}_{(i-1)\times(n-i)}\\
{\bf 0}^{\rm T}_{i-1}& {\bf 0}^{\rm T}_{n-i}\\
{\bf 0}_{(n-i)\times(i-1)}& I_{n-i}
\end{bmatrix}.$$
Multiplying $X^{\rm T}_{(-i)} X_{(-i)}$ gives:
$$X^{\rm T} \begin{bmatrix} 
I_{i-1}& {\bf 0}_{(i-1)\times(n-i)}\\
{\bf 0}^{\rm T}_{i-1}& {\bf 0}^{\rm T}_{n-i}\\
{\bf 0}_{(n-i)\times(i-1)}& I_{n-i}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 
I_{i-1}& {\bf 0}_{i-1}& {\bf 0}_{(i-1)\times(n-i)}\\ 
{\bf 0}_{(n-i)\times(i-1)}& {\bf 0}_{n-i}& I_{n-i}
\end{bmatrix} X\\
=X^{\rm T} \begin{bmatrix} 
I_{i-1} I_{i-1}       +{\bf 0}_{(i-1)\times(n-i)} {\bf 0}_{(n-i)\times(i-1)}&
I_{i-1} {\bf 0}_{i-1} +{\bf 0}_{(i-1)\times(n-i)} {\bf 0}_{n-i}&
I_{i-1} {\bf 0}_{(i-1)\times(n-i)} +{\bf 0}_{(i-1)\times(n-i)} I_{n-i}\\
{\bf 0}^{\rm T}_{i-1} I_{i-1} +{\bf 0}^{\rm T}_{n-i} {\bf 0}_{(n-i)\times(i-1)}&
{\bf 0}^{\rm T}_{i-1} {\bf 0}_{i-1} +{\bf 0}^{\rm T}_{n-i} {\bf 0}_{n-i}&
{\bf 0}^{\rm T}_{i-1}  {\bf 0}_{(i-1)\times(n-i)} +{\bf 0}^{\rm T}_{n-i} I_{n-i}\\
{\bf 0}_{(n-i)\times(i-1)} I_{i-1} +I_{n-i} {\bf 0}_{(n-i)\times(i-1)}&
{\bf 0}_{(n-i)\times(i-1)} {\bf 0}_{i-1} +I_{n-i} {\bf 0}_{n-i}&
{\bf 0}_{(n-i)\times(i-1)}  {\bf 0}_{(i-1)\times(n-i)} +I_{n-i} I_{n-i}
\end{bmatrix} X$$
$$\begin{align}
&= X^{\rm T} \begin{bmatrix}
I_{i-1}       +{\bf 0}_{(i-1)\times(i-1)}&
{\bf 0}_{i-1} +{\bf 0}_{i-1}&
{\bf 0}_{(i-1)\times(n-i)} +{\bf 0}_{(i-1)\times(n-i)}\\
{\bf 0}^{\rm T}_{i-1} +{\bf 0}^{\rm T}_{i-1}&
0 +0&
{\bf 0}^{\rm T}_{n-i} +{\bf 0}^{\rm T}_{n-i}\\
{\bf 0}_{(n-i)\times(i-1)} +{\bf 0}_{(n-i)\times(i-1)}&
{\bf 0}_{n-i} +{\bf 0}_{n-i}&
{\bf 0}_{(n-i)\times(n-i)} +I_{n-i}
\end{bmatrix} X\\
&= X^{\rm T} \begin{bmatrix}
I_{i-1}& {\bf 0}_{i-1}& {\bf 0}_{(i-1)\times(n-i)}\\
{\bf 0}^{\rm T}_{i-1}& 0& {\bf 0}^{\rm T}_{n-i}\\
{\bf 0}_{(n-i)\times(i-1)}& {\bf 0}_{n-i}& I_{n-i}
\end{bmatrix} X.
\end{align}$$

That thing between $X^{\rm T}$ and $X$ is a $n$-order identity matrix but with a zero in the $(i,i)$ entry; express it as $I_n$ minus a $n$-order matrix with zeros everywhere but a one in the $(i,i)$ entry:
$$\begin{align} X^{\rm T}_{(-i)} X_{(-i)} &= X^{\rm T} (I_n -e^{(n)}_i e^{(n)\rm T}_i) X\\ &= X^{\rm T} I_n X -X^{\rm T} e^{(n)}_i e^{(n)\rm T}_i X\\ &= X^{\rm T} X -(e^{(n)\rm T}_i X)^{\rm T} e^{(n)\rm T}_i X. \end{align}$$
That thing $e^{(n)\rm T}_i X$ represents the $i$th row of $X$, that is, $x^{\rm T}_i$.
$$X^{\rm T}_{(-i)} X_{(-i)} = X^{\rm T} X -x_i x^{\rm T}_i.$$
I hope this way is easier and not so tedious.